# Convert a string to list with variables

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I am trying to convert a string to a list.

```
stringvalue = '[54.0, country, state]'
```

I came across many answers but all of them the strings will have quotes like this

```
[54.0, 'country', 'state']
```

So my idea is I want a list like this

```
[54.0, country, state]
```

Basically, the country and state are variables which will get resolved in the program.

After looking around I came across an answer which removes the quotes(') around the string using this

```
class MyStr(str):
    """ Special string subclass to override the default representation method
        which puts single quotes around the result.
    """
    def __repr__(self):
        return super(MyStr, self).__repr__().strip("'")

MyStr(stringvalue)
```

This resulted in output that looks like list (without the quotes)

```
[54.0, country, state]
```

But the type is `__main__.MyStr`.- not list what I am looking

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: Do you know the values of country and state variables?

Comment: `eval(stringvalue)` will work as long as `country` and `state` are already defined, or `eval(stringvalue, locals=dict(country='US', state='GA'))`

Comment: So `country` and `state` are *placeholders‽* Then you want a simple substring replacement, or you want to write a mini parser for your mini expression language which can evaluate custom keywords like this.

Comment: @deceze yes country and state are like placeholders.

Comment: @DanielMesejo they are like placeholders

Comment: @PeterWood: `eval()` doesn't accept a `locals=` keyword argument (or any others I believe).

Comment: JohnG: What exactly would `country` and `state` be in the list you desire?

Comment: Why is your list a string in the first place? It would seem you may be converting a list to string and then back again?

Comment: @martineau Sorry, you're absolutely correct. I should have said: `eval(stringvalue, {}, dict(country='US', state='GA'))`. See [**`eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). I've never understood why some functions don't have keyword arguments when it seems obvious they should.

Comment: @Peter Wood: Yeah, the docs seem inconsistent about that aspect of arguments. Anyway, that's better, but the result is a list *with* quotes—which the OP doesn't want (although I'm not really sure what that even means).

Answer (score 0):

Start by extracting the fields:

```
import re
fields = re.findall(r"(?:([^,\s]+)\s*,?\s*)+?", stringvalue[1:-1])
#['54.0', 'country', 'state']
```

Get a reference to the dictionary of the local variables:

```
country = 'USA'
state = 'MA'
variables = vars()
```

Lookup the fields in the dictionary. If they are there, fetch their values. If not, treat them as numbers:

```
[variables[x] if x in variables else float(x) for x in fields]
#[54.0, 'USA', 'MA']
```

Answer (score -7):

try this one.

```
mystr = 'random'
mylist = []
for char in mystr:
    mylist += char

print(mylist)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).